# Remote python Interpreter setting in PyCharm Comm 2021.2

Tags: docker, pycharm

I am trying to create a remote python Docker interpreter setting with Pycharm Community Edition 2021.2. I have installed the docker plugin and also have connected to the docker image with *Unix socket: UNIX:///var/run/docker.socket* which shows "connection successful". However, when I go python Interpreter setting to I can't see or find a way to give the path to the python inside the running docker.
Please does anyone have an idea about it, it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the Professional edition in order to use Docker as interpreter. Community edition only allows you to use python virtual environments, conda or python**.exe